# Is it possible to install Ubuntu 20.04 in MacOs M2 chip?

Tags: ros, ubuntu, macos

I am using ubuntu 20.04 in UTM virtual machine, but gazebo is not properly working. So I decided to install ubuntu 20.04 as dual boot but unable to make in M2 chip, any source from where I can install Ubuntu 20.04 as a dual-boot option with MacOS M2 chip for ROS 1, or is there an alternative method to use ROS 1 on higher version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Docker is a good alternative you can try. You can find the docker images for ROS- Distros and gazebo in [OSRF Docker Images](https://github.com/osrf/docker_images).

Also, I found this [Docker for Robotics](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLunhqkrRNRhaqt0UfFxxC_oj7jscss2qe&si=MqN-nA29iO4iImmd) playlist quite helpful and easy to understand and there are a lot other resources you can try.

Hope that helps.